# How to pass post request data to a separate view? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I currently have this view which sends a list of genres to a template to populate a dropdown box:

```
class GenreSearch(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'games/genresearch.html'
    context_object_name = 'genre_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Genre.objects.order_by("name")
```

This is the template:

```
{% if genre_list %}

<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select Genre</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
      {% for genre in genre_list %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ genre.name }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endif %}
```

What I want to do now is select a genre from this dropdown box, submit it, and use this view to return results based on which genre is submitted:

```
class GamesPageByGenre(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'games/allgames.html'
    context_object_name = 'game_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        #Return games whose genres include the genre id x
        return Game.objects.filter(genres__id=10)
```

So if the 'action' genre was selected from the dropdown box, submit this, get the ID for the genre action, then replace 
`genres__id=10` with `genres__id=genreID`

Comment: Well you define a `<form>` and the `action=...` of that form should redirect to a `{% url ... %}`, the name of the URL to a view that handles that form, and then you obtain the data through `self.request.POST['my_fieldname']`, although for searching, sometimes a GET request is used (with GET parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the url in dropdown:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/gamespagebygenre/?genre={{ genre.id }}">{{ genre.name }}</a>
```

And in the view make like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    genre_id = self.request.GET.get("genre")
    return Game.objects.filter(genres__id=int(genre_id))
```

Comment: When I do this I'm getting this error: `TypeError at /genre-results/5/

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`. 

Does the fact that calling `genre_id = self.request.GET.get("genre")` in a different view mean it's not receiving it properly or is it a different thing?

Comment: I just fix sorry, you have to put the ? before the parameter on url

Comment: Is it possible to send more than one piece of data in this query? For example, `?genre={{ genre.id }}">{{ genre.name }}/?userid={{user.id}}` ?

Comment: I figured out my query above, using an `&` instead of a `/` before `?userid` works